# Blender Evee to Unity - Can't Export GLTF with Embedded Textures

Tags: export, eevee-render-engine, unity, .fbx, gltf

I'm having trouble exporting textured objects from Blender Evee as .glb files and importing them into unity with the textures retained.

I followed the steps in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNqj66ndwXc) but am still unsuccessful.

You can see my attempt [here on youtube](https://youtu.be/o_A2R3ysn9o).

Thank you in advance for any assistance on this.

If there's another method for embeding textures such as with FBX that doesn't involve using Blender Internal Renderer that would greatly help.

**Blender 2.8 Steps**

1. For the Object's material, use a BSDF Shader with an image texture as the base color
2. Export it as glTF Binary (.glb)

**Unity Steps**

1. Import Custom Package [UniGLTF-1.27.unitypackage](https://github.com/ousttrue/UniGLTF/releases)
2. Import .glb using the New import option.

**Additional Info if Needed**

- Using Blender 2.8 Evee Rendering Engine (portable .exe) No Addons yet.
- Unity 2017.4.2f2 (Wish to avoid upgrading unless it is the only way.)
- Exporting as ".gltf Embedded" did not work either.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you exported `.glb` works in https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/? If so, I would report a bug on the UniGLTF package. If not, please report a bug on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO.